# Checkov custom policy for checking IAM role name

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, checkov

We have a specific policy to include region name for IAM roles

I've created custom policy for that, but It's not working:

```
definition:
  and:
      - cond_type: "attribute"
        resource_types:
            - "aws_iam_role"
            - "aws_s3_bucket"
        attribute: "name"
        operator: "regex_match"
        value: /(us(-gov)?|ap|ca|cn|eu|sa)-(central|(north|south)?(east|west)?)-\d/g
```

Does anybody know how to fix that and is that possible to check IAM role name using checkov?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by these regular expression:

```
"^.*(us(-gov)?|ap|ca|cn|eu|sa)-(central|(north|south)?(east|west)?)-\\d.*$"
```